# Argument section recovery for binaries

Tags: static-analysis, angr, security

I am developing a static analysis automation tool to help me on CTFs. It would be nice for me to discover from where a certain argument of certain functions is coming from (does it come from a writable section in the VAS? Or does it come from .rodata?). I have a need-to-know superficial knowledge of angr, I tried to look at the documentation and my approach would be to:

1. Generate the CFG of the binary
2. Get all the symbols of the binary and filter them for the functions I'm interested in
3. Get to know from which address these symbols are being called
4. Construct from the calling address its basic block and traverse backwards the CFG from it to find out how the corresponding register is being set

Am I having the right approach? How would you implement this with angr?